QR-like color image

Is this QR-like RGB image some standard, or it is a proprietary solution of a bank for a 2-factor authentication (by its own mobile application for scanning and interpreting it)?
If it is a standard, is there some standard way to read the content of it?

This type of QR code is a proprietary one from a company called Cronto (now OneSpan). It is used in financial transaction signing software (photoTAN) and is used by many banks.
See also

Information Security Stackexchange: How does the photoTAN (Cronto visual transaction signing) procedure work?
Cronto Visual Cryptogram color barcode

